# Using Struct as data model in a C# Winform client application

Tags: c#

I am really skeptical on using Struct as the data model through out our C# Winform client application. But my colleague insist there should not be a problem if we wrap those Structs in classes so they will pass by reference. Is he right we should keep using Struct? Or could you help point out problems about using Struct in a C# Winform client?

The reason of using Structs is because we receive data from network in byte stream format. His point is if `Marshall` the bytes stream into a struct is the fastest way. I suggest to use `Bitconvert` to convert each values into class members.

Comment: Need an example of what it will look like. The general rule of thumb is keep them below 16 bytes to avoid overhead when they are used.. since value types are copied by value. If they are just holding a reference to a byte array then I guess _technically_ there is no need for a class...

Comment: Firstly if he's claiming that classes use pass-by-reference by default, he should read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html. Next I'd suggest that marshalling the data like that is really brittle - and that it's *very* unlikely that this is the performance bottleneck. Why make such an important design decision for such an unimportant reason?

Comment: That's so true. A big thing people misunderstand is that pass-by-value is the default.. its just that reference types copy the reference value. We recently had that misunderstanding at my workplace. Incredible the experience some devs have and don't understand this.